# How To Make Element Static With Dynamic Page Content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a `div` element which I would like to be on the **right side** of the screen, but that **does not** update its **position** when the **content extends dynamically** the width of the page. I made some research, but it was unsuccessful. I know this can be done by using JQuery, but I don't know how. Any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a fixed position on your div:

```
div { position: fixed; left: something; top: something; }
```

That would "glue" your div to the screen at the position you specify without any javascript. And if you scroll through the page, the div will stay at the same position.